# No puedo mandar imagenes en laravel por correo electronico

Tags: laravel-8

Un gusto saludarlos compañeros, tengo una duda no se si me pueden orientar, estoy enviando correo electronico con imagen en laravel, si la imagen lo saco de un servidor de facebook, me lo manda correctamente, pero si lo saco del servidor de la empresa no me muestra la imagen
Esto pasa si lo mando del servidor de prueba

Pero si lo mando desde un servidor como facebook me carga de la siguiente forma

Estos datos me retorna cuando le doy inspecionar elemento